# Goto Out Of Bounds pop-up on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I started getting pop-ups saying "Goto out of bounds" when:

1. Battery died and booted upon charging.
2. While on a call, the call disconnected and I'd see the pop-up on screen.

What could be the issue?

iPhone 8 running iOS 14.6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your phone appears to be displaying a similar interface to the GUI used to display information from a mobile carrier (other examples can be found by calling `*3001#12345#*`, `*#21#`, `*#43#`, etc., though the exact interface may vary).

It looks like your phone is receiving data from the cell network that it cannot handle, so, if anything, I'd recommend contacting your carrier, but it isn't really something to be concerned about.